# „Stammt vom“ oder „kommt aus“?

Tags: difference

Ich lerne für eine Prüfung und ich musste die folgende Lücke befüllen:

> … Jedoch: Schon das Wort Student ist ein Partizip Präsens; es ____ Lateinischen „studens“ – „ein sich Bemühender“.

Ich habe „kommt aus“ gewählt, aber es war falsch. Die richtige Lösung ist „stammt vom“.

Zwei Sachen sind für mich nicht ganz klar:

- Was ist der Unterschied zwischen „kommt aus“ und „stammt vom“? Ich habe gedacht, dass sie Synonyme wären.
- Ich habe „kommt aus“ genommen, weil ich dachte, dass „stammen vom“ falsch war (ich habe gedacht, dass „stammen **aus**“ richtig wäre). Im [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/stammen) finde ich viele Beispiele mit „aus“, aber ganz wenig mit „von“. Wann soll ich „von“ nutzen?

Comment: Wird in der Aufgabe „Lateinischen“ wirklich groß geschrieben?

Comment: @Carsten: Ja, s. Duden (http://www.duden.de/suchen/dudenonline/Wort%20aus%20dem%20Lateinischen) „Wort aus dem Lateinischen“

Comment: @Thomas, eben. Wenn es hier kein Adjektiv ist, fehlt danach ein Satzzeichen.

Comment: @CarstenS Ich muss es später bestätigen, aber ich habe den Satz geschrieben genau wie es in der Übung ist. Vielleicht habe ich irgendwas verlesen, aber ich denke eher nicht.

Comment: @JSBach Wenn Du "Lateinischen" großschreibst, es also als anderen Begriff für "die lateinische Sprache" verwendest, dann ist "kommt aus dem" richtig, und der Satz ist danach beendet. "Es kommt aus dem Lateinischen. Es stammt von 'studens'". Ansonsten musst Du "lateinischen" kleinschreiben, weil es dann "studens" näher beschreibt: "Es stammt vom lateinischen (Wort) 'studens'". In diesem Fall benötigst Du keinen zweiten Satz für den Rest, und "stammt vom" ist richtig.

Comment: @HenningKockerbeck danke für den Kommentar. Ich werde es zu hause suchen, ob ich die Aufgabe wieder finde.

Comment: @loong Interessant, dass du das "ich" wieder kleingeschrieben hast. Das ist doch ein vollständiger, eigenständiger Satz in den Klammern, daher habe ich es von klein zu groß geändert. Was ist deine Argumentation für Kleinschreibung?

Comment: @Em1 Ich habe nicht gesehen, dass du das „ich“ gerade erst geändert hattest – das sollte kein _edit war_ werden. Laut Duden schreibt man das erste Wort eines in Gedankenstrichen oder Klammern eingeschlossenen eingeschobenen Satzes klein, wenn es kein Substantiv, Eigenname o. Ä. ist. Die entsprechende amtliche Regel ist vermutlich § 54 (4). Man setzt auch gemäß § 88 keinen Schlusspunkt. Zum Beispiel: _Damit wäre dieses Thema vorerst erledigt (im Einzelnen werden wir noch darüber berichten)._ jedoch: _Damit wäre dieses Thema vorerst erledigt. (Im Einzelnen werden wir noch darüber berichten.)_

Comment: @HenningKockerbeck hier hast du den Text: http://www.sueddeutsche.de/bildung/gleichberechtigung-im-studium-studenten-aeh-aeh-studierende-1.2355340 . Das ist groß geschrieben und mit "stammt vom".

Comment: @HenningKockerbeck hättest du ein Kommentar darüber?

Comment: Das ist offenbar ein Fehler in dem Artikel. Das "lateinisch" müsste klein geschrieben werden, weil es als Adjektiv verwendet wird. Beim Eintrag für [lateinisch](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/lateinisch) geht der Duden nicht näher auf diesen Punkt ein, aber beim Eintrag für [deutsch](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/deutsch). Demzufolge wird "das Adjektiv 'deutsch' nur in Namen, bestimmten namenähnlichen Fügungen und in Substantivierungen großgeschrieben". Keiner dieser Fälle trifft zu, also hat sich die SZ da auch mal vertan ;)

Comment: Danke für den Bestätigung :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"*es kommt aus*" ist eine allgemeine Quellenbezeichnung im Sinne von

> es kommt aus dem Lateinischen *PUNKT, SATZENDE!*

"*Es stammt ab von*" ist dem gegenüber eine ganz genaue Angabe der Abstammung. Daher ist in diesem Satz alleine

> es stammt vom Lateinischen 'studens' (ab)

richtig.

Analoge Beispiele wären z.B.

> Jean kommt aus Frankreich

und

> Jean stammt vom Grafen Wolkenstein ab

Comment: Könntest du bitte mir den Unterschied zwischen "stammt aus" und "stammt von" ?

Comment: ......erklären?

Comment: "stammt aus" bezieht sich auf eine örtliche Herkunft, z.B. "der Waschbär stammt aus Nordamerika". "stammt von" bezieht sich eher auf eine "vererbte" Abstammung, z. B. "der Homo Sapiens stammt zum Teil vom Neandertaler ab". Um dich vollends zu verwirren: "sie stammt aus gutem Hause" geht auch. :)

Comment: @alfa dankeschön!

Comment: @JSBach Was vielleicht etwas untergegangen ist, bei "kommt aus" fehlt außerdem der Artikel. In "stammt vom", Kurzform für "stammt von dem", ist das "dem" enthalten. Wenn Du "kommt aus" verwenden willst, müsste es "kommt aus *dem" sein. Dann käme allerdings noch die Frage dazu, ob man "Lateinischen" großschreibt und wo genau der Satz zu Ende ist. Dazu schreibe ich gleich bei der Frage noch einen Kommentar.

Comment: Was würdest du zu »kommt vom« in der Lücke sagen?